# Any software to view solar-system from non earthbound platform

Tags: windows-7

After searching a lot online, I was not able to spot a (Windows based) software that is able to provide a view of the motion of planets, along with their moons in our solar system, from outside of earth. Just like Stellarium is for earth bound platform.

I know skysafari is one of the software but that is specially designed for either IOS or androids are there any other software for Windows operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since i used stellarium but i remember you can set your planet of viewing origin

http://www.stellarium.org/wiki/index.php/Configuration

The positions of the stars in the sky is dependent on your location on Earth **(or other planet)** as well as the time and date. For Stellarium to show accurately what is (or will be/was) in the sky, you must tell it where you are. You only need to do this once - Stellarium can save your location so you won't need to set it again until you move.
To set your location, press F6 to open the location window. There are a few ways you can set your location:
Just click on the map.
Search for a city where you live using the search edit box at the top right of the window, and select the right city from the list.

Enter a new location using the longitude, latitude and other data.

Once you're happy that the location is set correctly, click on the “use as default” checkbox, and close the location window.

Also Home planet (i havent used in years also free)
http://www.fourmilab.ch/homeplanet/
it has an Orrery (not sure if that is what you are looking for)

Orrery allows viewing the solar system, including a selected asteroid or comet, from any vantage point in space, in a variety of projections.

also

theplanetstoday "dot" com is an online Orrery (sorry about the "dot" - I dont have reputation to post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 2):

[Celestia](http://www.shatters.net/celestia/) allows to view the motion of stars and planets from *any* vantage point in the universe.

> ... The free space simulation that lets you explore our universe in three dimensions. Celestia runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.
>
> Unlike most planetarium software, Celestia doesn't confine you to the surface of the Earth. You can travel throughout the solar system, to any of over 100,000 stars, or even beyond the galaxy.
>
> All movement in Celestia is seamless; the exponential zoom feature lets you explore space across a huge range of scales, from galaxy clusters down to spacecraft only a few meters across. A 'point-and-goto' interface makes it simple to navigate through the universe to the object you want to visit.
>
> Celestia is expandable. Celestia comes with a large catalog of stars, galaxies, planets, moons, asteroids, comets, and spacecraft. If that's not enough, you can download dozens of easy to install add-ons with more objects.

It is cross-platform and Windows binaries are available. Stellarium and Celestia are slightly different in scope, but it should be able to do what you describe.